# Docker cannot attach into container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using bitnami/symfony docker project (https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-symfony)

```
docker ps

    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    d42e336d7454        bitnami/symfony:1-debian-10      "/app-entrypoint.sh …"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   simplistiapp_app_1
    7f37c7c6fec8        bitnami/mariadb:10.3-debian-10   "/opt/bitnami/script…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   simplistiapp_mariadb_1
```

Then I am trying to SSH using:

```
docker exec –it simplistiapp_app_1 /bin/bash
```

Getting this error (worked yesterday):

```
Error: No such container: –it
```

What am I doing wrong? From the articles I've read this should work - it worked yesterday.

Comment: Are you sure you are running `docker exec -it simplistiapp_app_1 /bin/bash` exactly? `-i` and `-t` are definitely options to `docker exec`.

Comment: I pasted exactly as I ran it, yup...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be using some different character for `-` in `-it`

You can barely tell the difference here but compare the following:

Right: `-`

Wrong: `–`

Copy and pasting the following command will solve your problem:

`docker exec -it simplistiapp_app_1 /bin/bash`

Comment: Oh jeeze. Thank you! Good eye. That's what I get for copying commands from websites and pasting. Yesterday I probably typed it in. :)